# How to write this without dot notation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can someone please help me write the following, without using dot notation:

```
self.bounds.size.width
```

I have tried `[[[self bounds] size] width]`, but this results in an error. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you setting or getting? Why don't you want to use dot notation?  CGRect is a data structure as is CGSize.

Comment: getting, theres no reason for me not to use dot notation, but I have not used it anywhere else in my project - would be nice to keep it one way or another

Comment: notation looks like access to the members of structure so I do not like and avoid it in my projects; one is the reason why I hate c++ syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have brushed up against the ambiguity of dot syntax.

You want:

```
[self bounds].size.width
```

`-bounds` returns an `NSRect` C structure.   Thus, you use traditional dots to access the items within.

Comment: Excellent - thanks a lot. I have tried to avoid dot notation for a long while without knowing exactly why. This has shed some light on the issues it raises. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To avoid mixed notation, I might prefer to use a local temporary C struct variable:

```
CGRect myBoundsRect = [ self bounds ];
foo = myBoundsRect.size.width;
```

That way the difference between object messages and C structure member accesses is explicitly separated.